java objects not firing jess rule
i'm trying to incorporate jess into an existing java system. the part i want jess to replace picks players based rules involving gamesplayed, etc. i have developed rules in a standalone clip file which i execute inside eclipse. i have done this before on a similar system. on the current system when i move the data creation portion to java the data related rules don't fire. I've included samples of data created by java in problem code - f-1, same clp but with hard coded facts - f-10. i have just included one fact from each run to  save space.
java is clearly creating valid facts. one difference is MAIN::JCJessPlayer vs MAIN::player. i'm not sure what causes that.
so my question is why are these facts not causing the defrule test-for-a-fact to fire? any help would be appreciated.
john
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;  MatchBuilder goals:
;   1) everyone plays same number of games
;   2) player waiting the longest plays next
;   3) minimize teams with same players
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(import com.soundsoftware.boccemgrjess.JCJessPlayer)

(deftemplate player  (declare (from-class JCJessPlayer)))

(watch activations)


(defrule start-execution 
    (declare (salience 50))
        =>
    ; (facts) 
    (printout t "Executing"   crlf))

(defrule test-for-a-fact 
    (declare (salience 40))
    (player (initials ?i))
        =>
    (printout t "Player"  ?i crlf))

(defrule finalize
    (declare (salience -10)) 
    =>
    (facts)
    (printout t "Done"   crlf)
    )

Java generated facts
==> Activation: MAIN::start-execution :  f-0
==> Activation: MAIN::finalize :  f-0
Executing
f-0   (MAIN::initial-fact)
f-1   (MAIN::JCJessPlayer (available TRUE) (candidate FALSE) (class <Java-Object:java.lang.Class>) (gamesPlayed 0) (initials "LZA") (key "fe75d3c4-d6fc-483e-b3a9-f90d42b88849") (lastplaytime 100) (picked FALSE) (OBJECT <Java-Object:com.soundsoftware.boccemgrjess.JCJessPlayer>))

For a total of 11 facts in module MAIN.
Done
Hard coded deffacts
==> Activation: MAIN::start-execution :  f-0
==> Activation: MAIN::finalize :  f-0
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-1
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-2
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-3
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-4
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-5
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-6
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-7
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-8
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-9
==> Activation: MAIN::test-for-a-fact :  f-10
Executing
PlayerLZA
PlayerJZU
PlayerAZU
PlayerAZJ
PlayerJZC
PlayerPZH
PlayerBZU
PlayerKZU
PlayerMZW
PlayerDZW
f-0   (MAIN::initial-fact)

f-10   (MAIN::player (available true) (candidate false) (class <Java-Object:jess.SerializablePD>) (gamesPlayed 0) (initials "LZA") (key <Java-Object:jess.SerializablePD>) (lastplaytime 10) (picked false) (OBJECT nil))

For a total of 11 facts in module MAIN.
Done
So, it appears in deftemplate the variable name must match the class name.
NG
(deftemplate player  (declare (from-class JCJessPlayer)))
Works
(deftemplate JCJessPlayer (declare (from-class JCJessPlayer)))
